# Java call function when created in superclass

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm trying to create a game engine in Java that uses the syntax and structure of UnityScript, and i've got most of it figured out at the moment. The only thing i'm struggling with is being able to call functions when instantiating a class from the superclass.

Example:

Object superclass:

```
public class Object {
   public Object(){
       Start();
   }
   public void Start(){
   }
}
```

Gameobject subclass:

```
public class GameObject extends Object {
   public GameObject(){
   }
   public void Start(){
   }
}
```

The thing i want to happen is that when i create a new gameobject or anything that extends from a gameobject calls the Start() function when instanced, preferably without using the super() statement.

Comment: Why _preferably without using the `super()` statemend_? That's what it's for.

Comment: I want to keep the code as clean as possible, so i can just extend something from GameObject and letting it do it's thing without the extra code to call functions like Start() or OnAwake()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your method names to follow convention.

Have your super class implement a `private` method that does its general logic and then calls the `start()` method, possibly your sub class'. Put a call to this `private` method in the constructor of the super class.

Your superclass

```
public abstract class SomeObject {
   public Object(){
       objectStart();
   }
   private void objectStart(){
       // do something general
       start();
   }

   public abstract void start();
}
```

Gameobject subclass:

```
public class GameObject extends SomeObject {
    public GameObject(){
        // implicitly calls super() which will call objectStart() which will call start()
    }
    @Override
    public void start(){
    }
}
```

Now when any subclass of `SomeObject` gets instantiated, its `start()` method will get executed.

If you don't want the class to be abstract, just implement a no-op `start()` method

Comment: I would also recommend not having a class named `Object`.

Comment: What's a non-op method? Sorry if i'm sounding like a complete idiot, but i've only worked with unityscript =/

Comment: @WouterMellema A no-op method is a method without a body, basically that does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Parent no-argument constructors will be called automatically if you exclude the `super` statement, so your code will work as-is.